ImportError: cannot import name 'triu' from 'scipy.linalg'
Trying to use word2vec this is where the error is raised :
import gensim.downloader as api
word2vec_model = api.load("word2vec-google-news-300")

I tried to update my Scipy library version but it was still the same. I downgraded it, then to 1.12 since I found that triu , I deprecated in the last Scipy version. But still, the same error.

downgrading to scippy 1.12 solved the problem


The scipy.linalg functions tri, triu & tril are deprecated and will be removed in SciPy 1.13.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release/1.11.0-notes.html#deprecated-features
you need :
pip install "scipy<1.13"

precisely,
pip install scipy==1.12

